# How to give results generated by select statement as a input to the same select statement in sql

Tags: sql

hi friends How to give results generated by select statement as a input to the same select statement  in sql using single table

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [Recursive Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

The example at the link above (shown below) shows how you can make your query a Common Table Expressions (CTE) and then in your query of that CTE, you can join to it again.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
WITH DirectReports (ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, DeptID, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, edh.DepartmentID, 
        0 AS Level
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
        ON e.EmployeeID = edh.BusinessEntityID AND edh.EndDate IS NULL
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, edh.DepartmentID,
        Level + 1
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
        ON e.EmployeeID = edh.BusinessEntityID AND edh.EndDate IS NULL
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON e.ManagerID = d.EmployeeID
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, DeptID, Level
FROM DirectReports
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department AS dp
    ON DirectReports.DeptID = dp.DepartmentID
WHERE dp.GroupName = N'Sales and Marketing' OR Level = 0;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery logic for your requirement.here is a code sample

```
  select A.* from (select * from mytable) A
```

Comment: SELECT empId FROM table1 where emp_id=174; here empId(one or more) will come and i want use the same result as emp_id in(here the list is first result) like this the loop should iterate

Comment: is this what u want.. select emp_id from table1 where emp_id in (SELECT empId FROM table1 where emp_id=174)

Comment: so now again you will get a list here so that list has to use as a input insted of 174

Comment: it is like a recursion in java